# How to remove the titlebar and resize the leftover of the titlebar in an Excel userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to remove the title bar in a userform in Excel.
Found a code on the internet, it works and removes the title bar but the form height remains.
This is the code.

Code for the userform:

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()      
        Call RemoveCaption(Me)      
    End Sub
```

Code for a module:

```
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" _ 
    Alias "FindWindowA" ( _ 
    ByVal lpClassName As String, _ 
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long 

    Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "User32" _ 
    Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _ 
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _ 
    ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long 

    Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "User32" _ 
    Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _ 
    ByVal nIndex As Long, _ 
    ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long 

    Private Declare Function DrawMenuBar Lib "User32" ( _ 
    ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long 

    Sub RemoveCaption(objForm As Object) 

        Dim lStyle          As Long 
        Dim hMenu           As Long 
        Dim mhWndForm       As Long 

        If Val(Application.Version) < 9 Then 
            mhWndForm = FindWindow("ThunderXFrame", objForm.Caption) 'XL97
        Else 
            mhWndForm = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", objForm.Caption) 'XL2000+
        End If 
        lStyle = GetWindowLong(mhWndForm, -16) 
        lStyle = lStyle And Not &HC00000 
        SetWindowLong mhWndForm, -16, lStyle 
        DrawMenuBar mhWndForm 

            End Sub 

    Sub ShowForm() 

        ThunderBarEndForm.Show False 

    End Sub
```

How can I resize the form height?

Comment: What is the question now? Either _How to remove the titlebar in an Excel userform entirely?_ as stated in the title of your post or _How can I resize the form height?_ as stated at the end of your post?

Comment: The code removes the titlebar of the userform but the height remains the same as if the titlebar is still there. Both questions are basically correct, how can I remove the titlebar entirely which also adjusts the height of the userform.

Comment: The code removes the titlebar and it removes it entirely. Removing the titelbar does not change the height of the userform. So, your first question is incorrect. Changing the size of the userform can be done at design time or run time, look [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-control-the-size-of-a-userform-in-excel-fab84047-506b-451c-8314-e24b74b4f70b).

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I checked the link but it‘s not what i was looking for. My situation is this, lets say my userform including the titlebar has a height of 20. 10 is the height of the titlebar, the other 10 is the userform. Using the code removes the titlebar but keeps the entire form at the same height of 20. If i go to vba editor, i am not able to resize the userform as it is at 10. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: What about adding `Me.Height = 10` to the initialize event?

Comment: Awesome! This solved my problem. Thank you.